# Does 逆さまにする ever mean rotation on the Y-axis? a twist?

Tags: words

I've thought さかさま to mean to rotate 180" over the X-axis. In dictionaries, I see the definition "to invert, upside down; to flip" ok.

But "*to reverse, back to front*" is also included in some dictionaries as a "secondary" definition for さかさま。This seems strange.

In daily use Japanese, さかさま 99% of the time means "rotate over the X-axis and turn something upside down. to invert / flip", right? And saying "さかさまにしろ" is like telling someone to "stand on their head"?

Comment: I've only ever encountered the _"reverse"_ sense in reference to either 1) the ordering of something, where 逆さまにする would mean to reverse the ordering, or 2) the inside-outness of something, where 逆さまにする would mean to turn something inside-out from its current state.  I've never seen 逆さまにする in reference to simply turning a single thing around so that it's back-to-front.  Do you have any sample sentences from your dictionary that illustrate this sense?

Comment: "逆にする" is what I'd heard in daily Japanese for reversing actions or intangibles. I don't think I've ever heard さかさま used before。For some reason, I think 逆さまにする requires the flipping of a physical object. I'm putting up Christmas decorations, and maybe that one would look better if physically flipped over (逆さまにした).

Comment: However, in that case, you're referring to "flipped top-to-bottom", yes?  That's the sense I'm familiar with for 逆さま.  Using 逆さま for "front-to-back" sounds odd to me.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi I'm mostly trying to brainstorm an answer for the question "how to say 'turn around!' in Japanese" But I think " 逆さまにしろ!" means "Stand on your head!"

Comment: ^ `"逆さまにしろ!" means "Stand on your head!"` <-- "Stand (on your head)" is intransitive so it should (at least grammatically) be [逆]{さか}さまに**なれ**. We usually say it [逆立]{さかだ}ちしろ, though. For "turn something upside down" we also have ひっくり[返]{かえ}す (intransitive: ひっくり返る). For "turn something inside out" we usually use [裏返]{うらがえ}す (noun: 裏返し), or ひっくり返す (but not 逆さまにする).  `"逆にする" is what I'd heard...` [逆]{さか}さまにする is more colloquial than [逆]{ぎゃく}にする.

Comment: If you just wanted to tell someone to "turn around" / face the other way, then you could try あっちを向いて if they're facing you, こっちを向いて if they're facing away from you, or 反対を向いて in general (in conversation you can omit を for all of these).

However, I have no idea what to say in the case of a car or vehicle. Maybe (車が)あっちを向いているようにして (if in a parking lot -- maybe you're filming or something), or Uターンして if driving.